# How do I create this table?

Tags: html, html-table

```
----------------------------
|     |       |  C   |  D  |
|  A  |   B   |------+-----|
|     |       | E    | F   |
----------------------------
```

Both A and B need a ROWSPAN of 2. What's the HTML for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you're using this for a layout, don't.  Use divs and CSS.

If you're using tabular data, then:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">A</td>
        <td rowspan="2">B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Harry Joy Thanks for that. :facepalm: